# Network restrictions on Tezos baking?

Tags: baking, network

I read [this article](https://forums.tezos.community/t/solar-baking-system-needed/183/53) about off-grid tezos oven, a computer capable to calculate tezos with power from a solar panel and water-mill only. Also [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/8vvdz9/if_you_drop_your_connection_whilst_solo_baking/) on Reddit let's us know that loosing the connection to other nodes for a while is not crucial mistake, if you not drop out of line for more than 24 hours. That means you don't have to be always online while baking.

Also from the same Reddit post I understood the asking of nonce is the action that is not allowed to be missed, but if you miss it, it would be resent to you.

Is there any network quality restrictions on tezos nonce asking? The Reddit post writer tells the nonce will be asked again on no reach situations, but are there also other network problems handled, like timeouts or dropping connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dedicated, always online connection is better. You have a small window to bake/endorse, and if you are offline when this occurs you will miss your turns and therefore rewards. If you bake a block with a nonce, you have the entire next cycle to reveal this, which is about 2 days and 20 hours.

Comment: What happen to the seed generation if one miner fails to reveal his nonce ?

Comment: There are 128 nonces per cycle, and all revealed nonces are used to generate the seed. Any baker who fails to reveal their nonce forfeits all rewards for the respective cycle (not bonds, just rewards).

Comment: thanks stephen that I understood by reading the doc but my question is what if there is only 100 nonces revealed is it enough to generate the seed ? what is the threshold to generate the seed ? What happen if we don't have enough nonce revealed to generate the seed ?